# Can you call .py(32bit) from .py(64bit)

Tags: python

Can I execute a 32bit python file from within a 64bit python file?

I use Teradata which relies on a 32bit infrastructure.  This is why whenever I need to query data I use python 32bit with teradata module to pull my data.  This is in one file called a.py.

The trouble is that the rows of data is too much for my 32bit python to handle as I keep getting memory issues.  Thus the need for 64bit version.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['python', 'a.py'])
```

I want to be able to run a.py from within my 64bit version and save the data in a dataframe df.
Is this possible?

Help much appreciated.

Comment: `subprocess.call` can run a different Python interpretor. Simply the command line will depend on the OS. So you should say what is the targetted system. And you will have to serialize the data between the 32 and 64 bits invocations.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I use Teradata" in this case? I don't think the massive data provider Teradata "relies on a 32-bit infrastructure". Is it possible you need to install the 64-bit versions of some Python modules for your 64-bit Python? What OS are you using?

Comment: In our company we are using the 32bit version of Teradata.  Thus the need for the 32bit environment.  I can not install the 64bit drivers for Teradata either. so I need to have a python with 32 bit environment to be able to connect to it.

Comment: @SergeBallesta how do you run a different python interpreter from within the subprocess.call? I know there is subprocess.Popen that might take env as variable

Comment: @SergeBallesta Thank your for your idea.  I managed to call python 32bit under python 64!

Answer (score 3):

There's no such thing as a 32-bit or 64-bit Python file. Python scripts do not have a specific architecture associated with them. They are compiled at runtime on the machine. If your OS is 64-bit, the data addressing is also 64-bit. If your OS is 32-bit, the data addressing will be 32-bit.

There is no real problem with calling Python scripts from another Python script. However, if you're asking whether calling the script using the 64-bit Python installation will open the subprocess in a 32-bit environment, the answer is no. I suggest that you install the 64-bit driver for Teradata instead and just run everything from a single script.

Comment: It's possible that their Python module happens to be importing extension modules (e.g. Numpy) which *are* architecture specific. But then still it should be possible to run the same pure Python code just in a different Python interpreter.